# Rendering to video file by SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I have written a program using SFML Library (in C++) rendering simple 2D animation.

I would like to save the animation to a video file instead of drawing it on the screen.

Does SFML provide such functionality? Is there any other, portable way to do this? (portable between different OSes)

Answer (score 5):

SFML does not have such a feature, especially since video processing is a whole world of its own. You can take a look at [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). Both libraries are cross-platform and should be able to record, playback and stream videos. If you want a specific codec, you could directly look at the codec's website and/or search for good encoder.

Overall it's not an easy task and depending on what you're trying to do, you could also think about grabbing the rendering directly with an third-party application, e.g. [Open Broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.com/) or (again) FFmpeg.

Comment: Thanks Lukas - I will think it over.